# Why is there a hover effect happening when I only specify click() jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a weird issue where when I am only using a `click` event to change the button color there seems to be a `hover` effect taking place has well and changing the button color when I leave the button. What's also weird is when I use this code with stack it does exactly what I want by only changing the color when I click, but both on my real environment and this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nkehzf1r/) the hover event is firing.

Basically works fine with Stacks code snippet, but JSFiddle and real environment do not.

```js
 $('.contract_links').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-primary');
 })
```

```css
 .pointer {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
  .contract_links {
   border-radius: 15px;
   border: solid 1px #cccccc;
   background-color: #e6e6e6;
   width: 150px;
   height: 35px;
   color: black;
   line-height: 35px;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="contract_links pointer" id="contract_overview">Contract Overview</div>
<br>
<div class="contract_links pointer" id="asset_covered">Asset Covered</div>
<br>
<div class="contract_links pointer" id="contract_history">Contract History</div>
<br>
<div class="contract_links pointer" id="contract_activites">Contract Activites</div>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but your snippet should be including jQuery _before_ the Bootstrap JavaScript file.

Comment: good call, changed it

Comment: Bootstrap buttons have a hover state that changes color... are you just unfamiliar with bootstrap that this is new information or is there something else?

Comment: I am familiar with bootstrap, I just didn't catch that. Thanks